# Powerpoint Macro to center align a single text box to slide

Tags: vba, textbox, alignment, powerpoint, center

I am trying to center align the text boxes in a large presentation. Each slide contains various shapes, but only has one text box with text in it, and I would like that text box aligned to the center of the slide. At the moment, I have a line of code that will make the text center aligned within its own text box, but I was wondering if there was a way of making the text box in the middle of the slide?

```
    Sub TextSize()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape


    With ActivePresentation

For Each oSl In .Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 26.5

                    ' change the code to make the text box centre aligned to the slide
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter


                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next

    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gopal's pointed you in the right direction.  After your code to center the text, add this:

```
.Left = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width / 2
.Top = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 2 - .Height / 2
```

Comment: if the font is too large and the shape is a table. This doesn't work! Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The code answers a request to center a text box. A table is quite a different matter. Start a new thread with whatever code you have so far; include a screenshot of a sample slide, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Although not mentioned, but in case you are adding the textboxes on the slide through VBA code (as explained in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743980%28v=office.15%29.aspx) documentation), then I guess textboxes do not have a property to directly get aligned to the slide in a particular fashion(in your case centrally).

Having said that, I would also point towards a possible workaround which may be to set the **Top** and the **Left** properties of the textboxes in a **ratio proportional to the slide's** **height** and **width** chosen for your presentation.

This I think should centrally align the textboxes.

Comment: Thank you very much, as you suggested, I have now learned to use the proportional ratio for alignment.